# How to match beginning of variable in dash

Tags: sh

Is it possible to match beginning of string in dash (/bin/sh)?

This is the usual situation

```
var="Hello"
if [ "$var" = "Hello" ]; then echo "Match"; fi
```

But sometimes it could be `"Hello World"`, `"Hello Kitty"` or something like that.
Tried with asterisks here and there (eg. "Hello*"), but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` with `glob`.

```
case "$var" in
"Hello"*) echo "Match"; ;;
esac
```